# Как задать медиа-запрос для процентного масштабирования?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как задать медиа-запрос для масштабирования?
На масштабе окна браузера 90% едет заголовок. Как узнать, какова ширина экрана на 90% (и так далее), чтобы правильно прописать медиазапрос? Спасибо :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Медиа-запросы пишутся в пикселях.

в google chrome -> откройте консоль (F12) -> при изменении размеров окна броузера справа вверху будут его габариты в "px"

Собственно, когда начинаются проблемы с версткой используется конструкция медиа-запросов:

```
css:

h2{ 
  font-size: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px){
   h2{
     font-size: 32px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но он немножко не о той проблеме :) Решение нашёл самостоятельно, сейчас отвечу

Answer (score 3):

Всё, разобрался методом эксперимента сам.
***Задача:*** узнать, какое разрешение экрана на **определённых процентах масштаба**.
***Решение:*** работаю в Google Chrome последней версии на момент ответа.
Вызываем панель разработчика нажатием комбинации клавиш Ctrl+Shift+I, находим в верхней части браузера под поисковой строкой процентные показатели и выбираем 100%.
Смотрим на разрешение, например, 1115 х 613px (у меня такой размер экрана, у вас может быть по-другому), нажимаем на конец строки ввода ширины (в моем случае это после цифры "5") и зажимаем клавишу вверх на клавиатуре, следя за автоматическим изменением процентов слева на той же панели.
Готово.

Comment: Ты делаешь успехи... Это радует)) Держи плюс...

Comment: @Air большое спасибо за помощь)) Всё стало, как надо. Если бы не Вы, я бы ещё вопросов тридцать наплодил))